# Trying to create An arraylist of arraylists, but encountering this error:

Tags: java, arraylist

"Syntax error on token 'al1, VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token" on the x.add(al1); line. Any idea why this is occuring? Ignore line 3

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GameState {//creates a list of the three coins to work with
private ArrayUnsortedList<Coin> coins = new ArrayUnsortedList<Coin>(3);
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(3);
    private ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> al3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    x.add(al1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's not in an [initializing block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) (and I think that's what you wanted). Something like

```
{
    x.add(al1);
}
```

which will be copied into any constructor (so you could put it in the constructor).